# Unable to make private java.time.ZonedDateTime accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module

Tags: spring-boot, exception, junit5, java-17, unnamed-module

I am migrating the project from Java 11 to Java 17. While running the junit test cases, Getting below exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.time.ZonedDateTime(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.ZoneOffset,java.time.ZoneId) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @e6ea0c6
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor.<init>(PreferredConstructor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$1.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.InstanceCreatorMetadataDiscoverer.discover(InstanceCreatorMetadataDiscoverer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(MongoMappingContext.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:711)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:146)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
```

I have already tried adding below VM option in IntelliJ, but this is not working. Can someone please advise here ?

Edit Configurations-> Modify Otions -> Add VM Option

--add-opens java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED